# Change the background of a custom button( xml file ) based on String variable's value dynamically

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a custom button  `b` in an activity. I have defined 6 `xml` files for that button's background. Now I want to set one of those 6 xml files as the background of `b` based on a String `str` which can have 6 values.

For example

`str = "A"` then, button should have first xml file as background.

`str = "B"` then, button should have second xml file as background.

`str = "C"` then, button should have third xml file as background.

and so on.

I tried to put all these 6 xml files in `drawable` folder and I have used `b.setBackground(R.drawable.custom_button_1)`, but it is giving  an error as it is expecting an int value, and xml file not treated as an integer.\

Is there any proper way to achieve this or not?

If not please suggest me another way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetBackground require drawable not int as mentioned by you.
You can use

```
b.setBackground (ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.custom_button_1));
```

or

```
b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_button_1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String text = b.getText().toString();
if (text.equals("A")) {
b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_button_1);
}

if (text.equals("B")) {
b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_button_2);
}
and so on...
```